# Including covariates increases spatial patterning rather than reducing it

Tags: bayesian, spatial

I am fitting a series of Bayesian spatial models with an intrinsic conditional autoregressive (iCAR) structure. In these models, I begin by fitting an empty model (null) and then add successive sets of covariates based on a conceptual foundation.

I then map quantiles of the mean posterior spatial random effects, highlighting those with 95% credible intervals that do not contain zero.

Results show that including additional covariates *increases* the number of areal units with 95% credible intervals that do not contain zero. I have not seen this before in spatial models – rather I typically see the number of areal units with significant exceedance probabilities *decrease* when controlling for more variables. I am having difficulty explaining why controlling for more variables causes the spatial pattern to become more pronouced and am wondering if others have come across this in their own work.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be related to the phenomenon found in some multilevel models whereby adding more covariates can increase the second-level variance? This is discussed on the [Gelman blog](http://andrewgelman.com/2006/05/15/in_a_multilevel/) and in the Gelman/Hill book on multilevel modelling. Here, obviously, we're talking about CAR-distributed terms rather than random-intercepts, but I think it matches up.

Comment: This looks like the answer! I'll update you once I've had a chance to further examine this phenomenon.